# error while post data using webapi

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, mediatypeformatter

i have created webapi, i am facing some problem when i am posting the data using this api, i am very much fed up can anyone help me this.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
    JSONData = {
        "CommunityID": "2",
        "QueryDescription": "gopal",
        "CategoryID": "1"

    };


    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/api/querycontroller',
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: JSON.stringify(JSONData),

        success: function (data) {
            $("#button").html(data.responseText + "---------");
        },
        error: function (data) {
            $("#button").html(data.status + "---------" + data.responseText + "---------error");

        }
    });

</script>
<label id="button"></label>
```

------my controller is below.

```
      [ResponseType(typeof(Query))]
    [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody]Query Services)
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();

        try
        {

            Services.CommunityID = UserStatus.GetUserID(User.Identity.Name);
            Services = repository.Add(Services);

            response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, Services);

            // string uri = Url.Route(null, new { id = Services.QueryID });

            //  response.Headers.Location = new Uri(Request.RequestUri, uri);

            return response;
        }
        catch (Exception dd)
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }

    }
```

when i am posting without  contentType: "application/json", then it showing me error :  415---------{"Message":"The request entity's media type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' is not supported for this resource.","ExceptionMessage":"No MediaTypeFormatter is available to read an object of type 'Query' from content with media type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'.","ExceptionType":"System.Net.Http.UnsupportedMediaTypeException","StackTrace":" at System.Net.Http.HttpContentExtensions.ReadAsAsync[T](HttpContent content, Type type, IEnumerable`1 formatters, IFormatterLogger formatterLogger, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n at System.Web.Http.ModelBinding.FormatterParameterBinding.ReadContentAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Type type, IEnumerable`1 formatters, IFormatterLogger formatterLogger, CancellationToken cancellationToken)"}

Comment: read through:http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/content-negotiation

Comment: Can you paste the class definiton of 'Query'

Comment: i solve it, but how fool i am let me know you, i am getting the community from code behind like Services.CommunityID = UserStatus.GetUserID(User.Identity.Name); and i am posting static CommunityID:2 , so obviously it will error. but now i fixed. thanks all